# How to change layout and template from module?

Tags: magento2, module

When creating a theme I can override the Magento header by placing files under
`app/design/frontend/company/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` and `app/design/frontend/company/mytheme/Magento_Theme/templates/header.phtml`

This works as expected. But I want to move my custom header into a module as I'd like to use it on other themes.

If I place the same files under the module directory (instead of them) the header doesn't update:

`app/design/frontend/company/module/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` and `app/design/frontend/company/module/Magento_Theme/templates/header.phtml`

How can I make layout and template changes from within a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try to below steps :-

**`1. How to Override Layout and templates files in theme`**

Layout :- **`/app/design/frontend/Company/Mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`**

templates :-
**`/app/design/frontend/Company/Mytheme/Magento_Theme/templates/header.phtml`**

**`2. How to Override Layout and templates files in Module`**

Layout :-
**`/app/code/Company/MyCustomModule/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`**

templates :-
**`/app/code/Company/MyCustomModule/view/frontend/templates/header.phtml`**

After All Changes you need run below commands :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

Correct path is `[Vendor]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/layout` and `[Vendor]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/templates`